# почему не срабатывает json_decode в PHP?

Tags: php

```html
<? $courseDates = !empty($param['card_dates2']) ? json_decode($param['card_dates2']) : [];?>
                    <? $i = 0; ?>
                    <?foreach($courseDates as $courseDate){?>
                        <?if (strtotime($courseDate) > time()) {?>
                            <div class="c-style_display_flex c-style_align-items_center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                                <span class="c-style_nowrap2"><?=$i + 1?> дата</span>
                                <input readonly data-id="<?=$i++ +1?>" style="margin-left: 5px;" class="j-datetimepicker" type="text" name="card_dates2[]" value="<?= $courseDate ?? '' ?>" placeholder="">
                            </div>
                        <?}?>
                    <?}?>
                    <div class="c-style_display_flex c-style_align-items_center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <span class="c-style_nowrap2"><?=$i + 1?> дата</span>
                        <input readonly data-id="<?=$i++ +1?>" style="margin-left: 5px;" class="j-datetimepicker last" type="text" name="card_dates2[]" placeholder="">
                    </div>
```

а когда пытаюсь вытащить из внутреннего массива card_dates2 обЪект он выдает элемент который расположен по порядку. то есть как я понял там строки остались а не массив!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А что в card_dates2?

Comment: ну это 2 блок с таким кодом там даты!

Comment: Нет, вы ПОКАЖИТЕ, а не расскажите

Comment: добавил скрин!))))

Comment: вообще, лучше текстом.....всегда... причём в виде воспроизводимого (настоящий массив или объект или строку).....а целом, судя по скрину, тут json_decode не нужен, т.к. это уже массив....либо должно быть так `json_decode($param)['card_dates2']`  но без полного понимания что у вас там в $param в целом - не ясно до конца

Comment: Какой код ошибки?

Comment: ошибки нет! просто выводит вместо обьекта массива. елемент строки!

Comment: $param это массив все данный страницы находятся там!

Comment: если param - массив и card_dates2 массив, то json_decode тут не к  месту

Comment: я же правильно понимаю что если хочу вывести данные из декода то нужно обращаться к $courseDates?

Comment: Вы кажется слушаете, но не слышите. Давайте в лоб: зачем вы написали json_decode? И знаете ли вы что она делает и для чего?

Answer (score 0):

Все разобрался! Дело было не в бабине! просто нужно было продублировать во второй php файл эту команду и оттуда вызывать и все заработало!